# Testing multi-tenancy Laravel applications using Behat / Mink and Behat Laravel Extension

Tags: php, laravel-5, multi-tenant, behat, mink

I am building a multi-tenant SaaS application which I am trying to write tests for with Behat, using Mink and the [Behat Laravel Extension](https://github.com/laracasts/Behat-Laravel-Extension)

When you register for an account, you get your own subdomain on the site `{account}.tenancy.dev`

my `behat.yml` file looks like so:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Laracasts\Behat:
            # env_path: .env.behat
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            default_session: laravel
            base_url: http://tenancy.dev
            laravel: ~
```

I am having problems straight off the bat as when I try to test my registration flow, I am getting a 404 error testing that the new subdomain is accessible, all of the data has been saved correctly, manually testing the process works and the subdomain routing works.

I was wondering if there was any way to do this using Behat and how I would go about setting Behat / Mink to use wildcard subdomains to test SaaS applications?

I am running the test inside the Homestead VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a short while I revisited this problem and found a rather simple solution to be used in my `FeatureContext.php`:

```
$this->setMinkParameter('base_url', $url);
```

This changes the base url for any scenario it is used in:

```
/**
 * @Given I visit the url :url
 */
public function visitDomain($url)
{
    $this->setMinkParameter('base_url', $url);
    $this->visit('/');
}
```

Which is used in the following way:

```
Scenario: Test Multi Tenancy
  Given I have a business "mttest"
  When I visit the url "http://mttest.example.com"
  Then I should see "mttest"
```

Obviously this is slightly contrived but does show that what I was intending to do is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The `base_url: http://tenancy.dev` configuration is used to generate a fully qualified domain URL when you utilize relative path URL's in your mink steps (IE "/home").

When you want to hit a domain different from the domain specified in `base_url`, all you have to do is use the fully qualified domain URL in your step like "http://test.tenancy.dev/fully/qualified".

So use the `base_url` configuration to set what you will be using for the majority of your steps as relative url's and then explicitly specify the full domain for the exceptions.

`When I create an account named foo
And GET "http://foo.tenancy.dev/ping"
Then I get a 200 response code`


`When I GET "/home"
Then the response contains "Sign Up"`

If the majority of your testing will be against the sub domain, set that as your `base_url` and explicitly specify your top level domain when necessary.

Comment: This is what I was doing and it gives me a 404 error because Behat runs the code in  a sandbox and as such, the subdomains are never added to the sandbox. I think what I need is Behat to allow something like wildcard subdomain handling.

Comment: What you're describing isn't a Behat responsibility. Configuration to allow your sandbox host to respond to *.domain.com comes down to your web server (apache, nginx, etc) configuration. I suspect you just need to configure your sandbox web server to direct all traffic to *.tenancy.dev to your application dir.

Answer (score 0):

You may resolve subdomains using [xip.io](http://xip.io/), which is especially useful if you cannot access the /etc/hosts file on a CI server, for example.

To route `{account}.tenancy.dev` to your local webserver, you can use `account.tenancy.dev.127.0.0.1.xip.io` which resolves to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I am not sure if Behat will work with xip.io but I'll try it now and let you know what happens.